# Определение смены SIM

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Есть задача: задетектить, когда юзер поменял симкарту. Можно отловить смену самой симкарты, но я пока не пойму, как лучше это сделать. Т.е. приложение может детектить только в двух вариантах, когда оно активно и когда в бэкграунде. Я так понимаю, что нужно создавать поток с таймером при запуске приложения, который будет отслеживать каждые, например, 2-3 секунды на наличие симкарты. Правильно? И не будет ли это садить батарею быстрее?

Comment: Конечно, будет садить. Ещё как будет садить. Тем более, это же айфон, а здесь подобные вещи делать в бекграунде как бы не совсем законно.

Посмотрите на это с другой стороны. Если меняется сим карта, то радиомодуль должен перезапуститься. Значит следует поискать подобные сообщения от системы и подписаться на них (не знаю, есть ли в айфоне подобная возможность, но в нормальных осях есть). Также можно перепроверять при старте устройства. И всех делов.

Comment: Я как бы и нашел ответ на свой вопрос на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872117/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-the-sim-phone-number-has-changed, НО оно не работает. Там, я так понимаю, что запускается очередь, которая проверяет смену карты. Добавил этот код в метод, когда приложение активно, и в метод, когда приложение неактивно. При вытаскивании симкарты код не срабатывает и при вставке тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: @iSerg, В iOS для разработчиков ПО нет возможности непрерывно выполнять операции в фоне. Либо вы сами завершите приложение из кода, либо iOS принудительно завершит. Времени даётся по-разному в зависимости от настроек, сколько, точно не помню, примерно 30 секунд. Если использовать "Background fetch", то интервал будет таким же, но запускаться задача будет случайным образом (почти, там анализируется активность). Подписаться на системное уведомление можно, но от этого ваше приложение запускаться не будет, даже в фоне.

Comment: Это я тоже вкурсе. Весь прикол в том что код указанный мною в ссылке - не работает и я непойму почему. Т.е. там данные об операторе появляются (как только симку вытянуть), но после того как ее вставить обратно, не срабатывает код внутри блока, да и к блок снова не вызывается.